# Tokenizing CString issue with the Tab Space character

Tags: c++, windows, string

I'm trying to split a `CString` in two whenever there is a `"\t"` (tab space) character. This is the code I'm using:

```
CString val = data->str;
CString valTok;
CString accTok;

int indx = 0;
valTok = val.Tokenize(_T("\t"), indx);
++indx;
accTok = val.Tokenize(_T("\t"), indx);
```

Its great and all, but the first character of `accTok` is missing. For example, when `val = "String1\tString2"`, `valTok = "String1"` but `accTok ="tring2"` ... how come?

**EDIT:**

So following hvd's advice I removed the `indx` increment and I have the following code:

```
CString val = ((CItemData*)lpDrawItemStruct->itemData)->str; // Was this value causing the problem in the end
CString valTok;
CString accTok;

int indx = 0;
valTok = val.Tokenize(_T("\t"), indx);
accTok = val.Tokenize(_T("\t"), indx); // ASSERT(iStart >= 0) fails
```

But now the first `Tokenize` returns `-1` for some reason..! Any ideas?

**SOLVED:**

The problem was in the value passed to `val`:

```
((CItemData*)lpDrawItemStruct->itemData)->str
```

which was sometimes `NULL`, causing an assertion when calling `Tokenize` a second time in some cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lose the `++indx`.

From the documentation of [CStringT::Tokenize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4ftfkd2.aspx):

> The value of *iStart* is updated to be the position following the ending delimiter character, or -1 if the end of the string was reached.

After the first call to `Tokenize`, `indx` already points past the `'\t'`, it already points to the `'S'` of "String2". By incrementing `indx`, it will point to the `t`.

Here's a simple sanity check for `Tokenize`:

```
CString val;
CString str1, str2, str3;
int indx;

val  = _T("");
indx = 0;
str1 = val.Tokenize(_T("\t"), indx);
assert(str1 == _T("") && indx == -1);

val  = _T("String1");
indx = 0;
str1 = val.Tokenize(_T("\t"), indx);
assert(str1 == _T("String1") && indx >= 0);
str2 = val.Tokenize(_T("\t"), indx);
assert(str2 == _T("") && indx == -1);

val  = _T("String1\tString2");
indx = 0;
str1 = val.Tokenize(_T("\t"), indx);
assert(str1 == _T("String1") && indx >= 0);
str2 = val.Tokenize(_T("\t"), indx);
assert(str2 == _T("String2") && indx >= 0);
str3 = val.Tokenize(_T("\t"), indx);
assert(str3 == _T("") && indx == -1);
```

Do you get different results?

Comment: I just get an assertion error now: ATLASSERT( iStart >= 0 ) how come? I assumer its because Tokenize set it to -1, but why?

Comment: @user965369 "or -1 if the end of the string was reached." so you should stop calling `Tokenize` once it returns an empty string (an empty string signifies the end of the string was reached)

Comment: @user965369 That doesn't sound right. `indx` should only get set to -1 when `Tokenize` returns an empty string. So you've made sure `valTok` is not an empty string, yet the line that assigns to `accTok` gives an assertion failure? I'll include a minimal but full example program when I get the chance.

Comment: yeah that's what's happening! So weird, cheers man. Look forward to hearing from you.

Comment: @user965369 So what results do you get for the tests I've already included here? Any assertion failures?

Comment: I've updated the question:) The line str2 = val.Tokenize(_T("\t"), indx); causes the ASSERT

Comment: @user965369 If I copy and paste the exact code from your edited question into a new project (and disable Unicode in the project settings, as it otherwise won't compile without the `_T` macro), it runs as expected. I suspect that isn't the code that's failing, I suspect you've simplified it too much. Or are my suspicions wrong, and does that exact code show the problem?

Comment: No that's the exact code I'm using! Its literally copy and pasted straight form my project.

Comment: @user965369 In that case, either you have memory corruption somewhere (say, all `"\t"s` point to a shared static string, and you overwrite the `'\t'` byte), or your `Tokenize` doesn't behave as documented and as it does on my system. To rule out the former, can you copy that code to the start of your project's `main` function? If it works there, keep moving it to a later point until it starts failing.

Comment: Its cool I've fixed it! It was, as you initially suspected over simplified. The string I was assigning to val was being passed via the WM_DRAWITEM windows message and sometimes the message was sent with empty data so it was ASSERTing the non-intentional string manipulation. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: @user965369 Glad to help, but for future reference, when you say "No that's the exact code I'm using!", please make sure that's really the exact code you're using. You wouldn't get that problem with the hardcoded string `CString val = "New\tCtrl+N";` you have in your updated question.